# What is the case against seeing the Medieval Catholic Church as oppressive?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, medieval-church

I have a professor who keeps mentioning a false claim regarding the Catholic Church during the Medieval Times that I know is historically untrue but I do not know how to give a concise counter-argument regarding these views.

My professor basically is stating the following thing that I need help answering and correcting:

> The Catholic Church in the Medieval Times was oppressive and monopolized knowledge because she wanted to suppress the common man from knowing what was going on.

Basically he states that the Church in the Medieval Ages prior to the printing press and the development of concepts such as Democracy wanted to keep people ignorant.

How can I show him that this is not true as evidenced by the various creations of universities during the Middle Ages and the monasteries which helped preserve education and manuscripts?

Comment: You're going to have to deal with the Catholic Church's opposition to vernacular translations and liturgies.

Comment: This seems a bit broad for this particular venue.  The only short answer is to get specific charges, not sweeping generic ones like the one listed, and then refute those.  Start with "Give me specific examples of how the Church suppressed knowledge".  Otherwise there's no reason to bother refuting the claim.  If the attacker can't produce the basis for the claim, then it's simply a baseless claim that should be ignored.  To try to address a baseless claim gives it credibility.  Demand specifics that can be proved or disproved, and refute the specifics.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Which opposition is not obscurantist; quite the contrary. As the [Baltimore Catechism](http://bit.ly/1F0OA3z) says: **Q. 566**. Why does the Church use the Latin language instead of the national language of its children?
**A.** The Church uses the Latin language instead of the national language of its children:
To avoid the danger of changing any part of its teaching in using different languages;
That all its rulers may be perfectly united and understood in their communications;
To show that the Church is not an institute of any particular nation, but the guide of all nations.

Comment: @Geremia promoting Latin is fine, executing those who translated the Bible (or even just the Lord's Prayer) is not. It may not have been common, but it happened.

Comment: @curiousdannii The [Inquisition](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08026a.htm) executed no one; the State did (see [this book](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/756454360)). The Church promoted mercy toward heretics more than their death (Luther was even invited to Trent, but he refused to go). Many who made translations (e.g., Luther) introduced heresies and errors into the translation; that is the problem with unregulated translations. The Church made many very good vernacular translations, e.g. the [Douay-Rheims](http://www.drbible.org/).

Comment: @Geremia when you have established churches it's hard to make that distinction. Would the state have passed the *De heretico comburendo* if the Church didn't want it? The state may execute heretics, but it's the Church who labels them so. Discussing these details isn't relevant to this topic. Recognising that the Church at times was opposed to translations is, I think. Remember it was only at Vatican 2 that the Mass was allowed to be done in other languages than Latin.

Comment: @curiousdannii Certainly Church and State were much closer back then than today.

Comment: @curiousdannii Not all rites use Latin officially. There were about a dozen languages used in Catholic liturgies before Vatican II (see the first footnote of [this](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~aversa/latin/language_gihr.pdf)).

Comment: @curiousdannii and Geremia -  Please avoid discussion in comments. Comments are not an acceptable medium for debate. Also, some of the comments here could be turned into the more focused, specific questions I suggested, so you can get the specific claim as well as the apologetic answer to it, all while earning rep and behaving constructively.

Comment: This might be a better fit for History.SE, since it's not really about Christianity, but rather about a Christian's organization in political history.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about political history.

Comment: Possibly related: [Did the Catholic Church stifle inovation in the Middle Ages](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/882/is-there-any-evidence-that-the-catholic-church-slowed-innovation-during-the-midd/975#975)

Comment: I think your professor is using exaggerated language, placing him on one side of the spectrum. If you are all the way on the other side, it's best to just ignore those statements. It'll just lead to an argument where both of you are wrong and strain your relationship with your professor, who controls your grade. About the question, I would try an [edit] that says "What are examples of how the Catholic church encouraged innovation and knowledge?" You already pointed out the creation of several universities, so that's one, assuming the circumstances support your side.

Comment: @Flimzy I'm not sure your reason is valid, but I would say that this question currently holds too much opinion, realizing that history questions like this do require some interpretation of events, but this one is worded to bring too much.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it invites too much interpretation to historical events, making it primarily opinion based. If you can narrow the scope toward factual events, then it would be better and probably on topic.

Answer (score 7):

I think, as is often the case, that in some times and places, the Church was co-opted by the Aristocracy. While the Church certainly had a vested interest in promoting learning, the Aristocracy did not. After all, Scripture is a revolutionary thing, and if the working classes (peasantry) became to well versed in exactly what the Bible teaches, they might be harder to control, and indeed even revolt. And given that the hierarchy of the medieval Church was often drawn from the Aristocracy, the notion that at least some elements in the Catholic church were oppressive, and attempted to keep some of the people from being educated, is at least a question worth pursuing. This is not to suggest, by the way, that all members of the Hierarchy of the church felt this way, but unquestionably some did.

On the other hand, the church did not always side with the aristocracy. In the New World, for example, the aristocracy as a whole sought from Rome a decree that the native peoples that they found here were not rational beings, as this would allow the locals to be put into slavery. However, the church refused, to the consternation of some of the Aristocracy in the new world.

I think this is yet another instance where the answer does not lie at either extreme, but somewhere in the middle. I would say, that in the long term, yes the Church did promote learning, and preserve the body of knowledge. However, in some times and in some places, it was less noble in this regard than in others.

Answer (score 3):

The Catholic Church—since at least the time of [Charlemagne](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03610c.htm), his tutor [Alcuin of York](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Alcuin_of_York.aspx#1), et al.—promoted learning, established parochial schools, and laid the foundations of the modern university. The Church is "the pillar and ground of truth" (1 Tim. 3:15).

If the Church were obscurantist, then why do so many cathedrals have such beautiful artwork, which very effectively instructed illiterate and literate people alike in the truths of Holy Scripture?

It is also a myth that only the clergy had access to Holy Scripture. Although wealthy medievals certainly had more elaborate [Books of Hours](http://www.medievalbooksofhours.com/), some poorer literate medievals carried around simpler ones, too, reading them throughout the day. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVqrYXivZM8) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXISnFgFnp4) (and [these](http://www.medievalbooksofhours.com/media#videos), too) for [an introduction to Books of Hours](http://www.medievalbooksofhours.com/learn) and [this website for pictures of medieval Books of Hours](http://www.medievalbooksofhours.com/).

The following is an excellent historical work which overviews the medieval university, preparatory schools, popular education, technical education, women, hospitals, law, and economics:

Walsh, James Joseph. *[The Thirteenth, Greatest of Centuries](http://www.strobertbellarmine.net/books/Walsh--13th_GOC.pdf)*, 1907.

In addition to spreading truth, the printing press also made it easier to spread error, untruths, and heresy. This certainly concerned the Church, and the Church's love for seeking truth and defending it prompted the establishment of the [Inquisition](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/756454360) (which did not execute a single heretic; the State, however, did).

Comment: The state was the executioner acting at the behest of the church

Comment: @Kris The Church, which desires the conversion more than the death of heretics, never told the State to execute a heretic. The Church judged someone a heretic, and the State judged whether to apply the death penalty to the heretic. cf. the [Inquisition _CSE_ article](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08026a.htm)

Comment: Semantics if the Church  had expressed disapproval of the executions they would have stopped and the state would have had no interests in killing these people without the church declaring them heretics

Answer (score 3):

The answer is [Europe and the Faith](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/089555464X) by Hilaire Belloc.

He consistently and logically argues that the fallacy that you bring up is a result of collusion between the the North Germans who think their ideas and philosophy are better than everyone elses and the English aristocracy who found it necessary (until WWI) to have a close philosophical and spiritual alliance with the Germans to keep down popular uprisings of Catholicism within their nation (It was really quite dead by then).

He further says that because they (the Germans, or Teutons) were so late in the game to join with the Catholic Church, that the faith had no sticking power with them and they were the first to abandon it.  So, because they like to claim ([falsely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_in_the_Middle_Ages)) that they were the first to translate the Bible into the vernacular, and that that somehow brought forth enlightenment in to the world.

The truth is, the Dark ages were dark because there was a lot of reorganization going on.  The Middle ages, on the contrary, were not the dark ages, they may not have been pleasant, but there was a lot less slavery and a lot more feasting during that time period.  The dark ages were the period in which Catholicism defeated barbarism and the middle ages were when we remembered the antiquities, the renaissance, reformation and enlightenment (and all periods until the 20th century, where Plato and Aristotle are finally getting back in fashion [according to the Collected works of Aristotle]), were all reactions against the collective wisdom and tradition of mankind.

That, sir, is what your professor fails to profess, he thinks the greatest good is progress.  Catholicism teaches that the greatest good is God and that God can only be truly known through Tradition.